# 2 Datepicker 's different format on jQuery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to do simple task :

show 2 datepickers :

one - by `month and year` , seocond - `regular`.

i *have* succed to find the css style which hides the calendar part and show only the month and year :

```
<style type="text/css">
      .ui-datepicker-calendar {    display: none;    }​
</style>
```

but i cant find away telling : this `datepicker` instance *SHOULD* self-apply this css  ,and the other should *NOT*.

how can fix my **[code](http://jsbin.com/ihalun/edit#source)** to apply the css *only* to 1 control ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a second class explicitly to the date picker that has `display: none` as its only attribute, or explicitly set the `style` of the restricted date picker, e.g.:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').first().css('display', 'none');
```

**EDIT 1** that doesn't work - the two date pickers share the same elements so you can't tell them apart like that.

**EDIT 2** The best I've been able to do so far is to add this:

```
$('#datepicker').click(function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
});
```

Which *does* hide the calendar, but does unfortunately make it appear very briefly before it disappears.

**EDIT 3** Solved! :)

The trick is to apply your global CSS to every date picker so that they're *hidden by default*, but then explicitly *show* the calendar fields for the other one whenever it's triggered:

```
$('#datepicker2').click(function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').show();
});
```

This is much more visually appealing than having the calendar appear for a fraction of a second and then disappear again.

NB: you may have to register this handler for any other UI events that will cause the date picker to appear - `.click()` on its own may be insufficient.

Working demo at http://jsbin.com/oredoy/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are using the same css class for both datepickers -> they will both behave the same (as expected).

Define 2 separate classes "ui-calendar-monthYear" and "ui-calendar-regular" and assign them to your datepickers.

Comment: the date picker object is created (and has its classes defined) by the jQuery UI library